# using rest and parsing xml in python

Tags: python, xml, rest

I have a python script that does a REST GET call and stores the xml response in a string "response". However when I try to print the root of the XML, it fails with the following error.  If i just print response i.e "print response.read()", I get the response body correctly. What could be wrong here? Could you please help?

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = "http://192.168.1.1/health"
headers = {"Content-Type":"application/xml"}

request = urllib2.Request(url)

for key in headers.items():
  request.add_header(key)

response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

#print response.read()

root = ET.fromstring(response)

#print root
```

Here is the error when executing the script

```
~]# python test4.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test4.py", line 24, in <module>
    root = ET.fromstring(response)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 963, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1245, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, 0)
TypeError: Parse() argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not instance
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
root = ET.fromstring(response)
```

to

```
root = ET.fromstring(response.read())
```